Highlight Main Menu button when on an active page of the menu or submenu
How can I highlight the main menu button on the nav bar when I am on a page in either the menu or on the sub-menu? I already created an active class in CSS but I am not sure how to handle the JavaScript. This is a huge application with multiple pages so the goal is to make it as dynamic as possible.
This is my current code:
.dropbtn:active {
  background-color: blue
}



<div id="headerDiv" class="divHeaderLoginButton">
  <div style="width:1120px; margin: 0px auto;">
    <div id="menu" style="display:none;">

      <button id="btn1" class="dropbtn">Home<i class="down"></i></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content divH">
        <button class="subMenuBtn" id="btn11">Main Menu <i class="right"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content divH" id="dv1">
          <a href="/About" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">About</a>
          <a href="/Index" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Index</a>
          <a href="/DisplayTeam" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Display Team</a>
        </div>
        <button id="btn12" class="subMenuBtn">Shop <i class="right"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content divH" id="dv2">
          <a href="/Jewelery" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Jewlery</a>
          <a href="/Clothes" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Clothes</a>
          <a href="/Shoes" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Shoes</a>
          <a href="/Accessories" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Accessories</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


Change your css to use .active, not :active.
Add event listeners for mouseover and mouseout to add and remove your active class on the main menu button.
My best understanding is that by "main menu button" that you meant the "Home" button, but the code can easily be changed if you meant a different button.
Note that changed the menu to not be hidden, so the snippet would show the code in action.


let mainMenu = document.querySelector( ".dropbtn" )

for( let menu of document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-content") ) {
  menu.addEventListener( "mouseover", event => {
    if( event.target.tagName=="A" || event.target.tagName=="BUTTON" ) mainMenu.classList.add("active")
  } )
  menu.addEventListener( "mouseout", event => {
    if( event.target.tagName=="A" || event.target.tagName=="BUTTON" ) mainMenu.classList.remove("active")
  } )
}
.dropbtn.active {
  background-color: blue
}
<div id="headerDiv" class="divHeaderLoginButton">
  <div style="width:1120px; margin: 0px auto;">
  
  
      <!-- EDIT Made menu visible for demo -->
      <!-- <div id="menu" style="display:none;"> -->
      <div id="menu">

      <button id="btn1" class="dropbtn">Home<i class="down"></i></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content divH">
        <button class="subMenuBtn" id="btn11">Main Menu <i class="right"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content divH" id="dv1">
          <a href="/About" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">About</a>
          <a href="/Index" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Index</a>
          <a href="/DisplayTeam" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Display Team</a>
        </div>
        <button id="btn12" class="subMenuBtn">Shop <i class="right"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content divH" id="dv2">
          <a href="/Jewelery" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Jewlery</a>
          <a href="/Clothes" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Clothes</a>
          <a href="/Shoes" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Shoes</a>
          <a href="/Accessories" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Accessories</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




Thanks this is very helpful. It accomplishes some of what i wanted to do. To be more clear on the ask, i want the Home button highlighted when i am on the About, page or jewelery page or one of those pages nested under the submenus in the home menu

If you would like to add a simple highlight to the button when hovered on, try updating the border color, like this:
var btn11 = document.getElementById("btn11");

btn11.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  btn11.style.borderColor = "yellow";

});
btn11.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  btn11.style.border = "";
});


if the page is not reloading then you can add a class on click of the button and remove class from previously clicked menu through jquery.
I am adding the full code here.


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu button').on("click", function () {
    $('#menu button').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
.active {
  background-color: blue
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="headerDiv" class="divHeaderLoginButton">
    <div style="width:1120px; margin: 0px auto;">
      <div id="menu">
        <button id="btn1" class="dropbtn">Home<i class="down"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content divH">
          <button class="subMenuBtn" id="btn11">Main Menu <i class="right"></i></button>
          <div class="dropdown-content divH" id="dv1">
            <a href="/About" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">About</a>
            <a href="/Index" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Index</a>
            <a href="/DisplayTeam" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Display Team</a>
          </div>
          <button id="btn12" class="subMenuBtn">Shop <i class="right"></i></button>
          <div class="dropdown-content divH" id="dv2">
            <a href="/Jewelery" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Jewlery</a>
            <a href="/Clothes" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Clothes</a>
            <a href="/Shoes" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Shoes</a>
            <a href="/Accessories" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Accessories</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>




What I have done in the past is put the following code in the css file
.dropbtn a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }

this changes the color when the objected is hovered over. If you want to be when clicked, I think there is another one other than hover to do that.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
